# .htaccess Redirect all Subdomains to an URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, subdomain

how can I redirect all of the subdomains to a URL
this is the scenario :

abc.xxx.com goes to abc.xxx.com/index.php?id=abc
www.xxx.com/abc or xxx.com/abc also goes to the same URL: abc.xxx.com/index.php?id=abc

and please bear in mind there is no /abc folder on the website

and the file index.php is the root file of the main domain

I want to keep the abc in the subdomain for SEO purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this but it will create an infinte loop 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www).+)\.xxx\.com[NC]

RewriteRule !^%1 https://%1.xxx.com/index.php?CN=%1&r=%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

I think you must first check if URL does not contain "index.php?id=" to prevent infinite loop.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php\?id= [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, actually it is working for index.php but all of my other files like css that I am calling inside the index , not calling properly because all are calling abc.xxx.com/index.php?id=abc